# Custom button for record edit form

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have used a custom button to submit the  updated record on LWC, used as quick action. In onclick funtion, I have used "this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(this.totalFieldList);" But when I submit the the values are still referred to the old values. Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you share your code so we have a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.